# Restore/change text/background colors in sharepoint online management shell

Tags: powershell, powershell-script

I changed colors under properties > colors to improve readability but:
1/ the colors don't reflect the changes I made
2/ I can't restore defaults or make any other changes.

I uninstalled and reinstalled the program, but the colors I changed persist.

Comment: Try launching PowerShell as Administrator. The "shell" colors are stored with the Shortcut used to launch PowerShell.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I always open as admin but I'll give it another shot.